# Найти сумму минимального и максимального числа массива python

Tags: python, массивы

Понадобилось решить классическую задачу, и я решил сделать это так:

```
mas = input().split()
b = int(max(mas)) + int(min(mas))
print(b)
```

Но когда я ввёл 10 чисел (-100 87 123 57 29 46 23 -100 12 1) получился ответ -13, хотя должен выйти 23, с чем это связанно?

Comment: `input()` возвращает строку. Когда вы применяете `max()` и `min()` к массиву строк, то получаете неожиданные результаты (проверьте сами). А пока - замените `input().split()` на `list(map(int, input().split()))` это введет массив **целых чисел**, далее код отработает верно)

Comment: Сработало, спасибо!